# Uninstall .ttf font which I installed earlier

Tags: fonts

I tried to uninstall .ttf font which I installed myself using "install" option in Font Viewer window but I can`t find the font listed in Font Manager or even in /usr/share/fonts/truetype. Any help?

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo updatedb && locate fontname.ttf` ?

Comment: @heemayl /home/ihab/.local/share/fonts/arial.ttf

Comment: Check my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the font do:

```
rm /home/ihab/.local/share/fonts/arial.ttf
```

This will remove (uninstall) the `arial.ttf` font from your system.

If you wish to just make it unusable rather than removing totally, move it to someplace other than the normal directories from where font files are read. For example:

```
mv /home/ihab/.local/share/fonts/arial.ttf /home/ihab/backup/
```

This will save the font file in `/home/ihab/backup/` directory.